# Need to sync two lists with atrribute time, but times aren't equal

Tags: algorithm, list, sorting, synchronization

I gonna try to describe my problem the best i can. I have two lists, one with audio frames and other with color frames (not relevant). Both of them have timestamps, they were captured at the same moment but at different instants. So, i have like this:

```
index  COLOR  AUDIO
0      841    846
1      873    897
2      905    948
3      940    1000
...     ...    ...
```

the frames start at high numbers because they were captured and then trimmed to specific parts, but im shot, frame 0 is synced with only 5ms apart(timestamp in ms).

On every case i have, the audio frames count is less than the color count. I need to make them have the same count. The stating frames may be color>audio, color

edit:
i have more than 4 frames on each list.
the times between frames are not constant.

edit2:
this was captured using kinect, althought i think its irrelevant, i cannot capture the data again

edit3: Someone asked why i needed to sync the times. i'm using this to develop a multimodal emotion recognitino system and i need to train a decision level classifier (KNN), so i need the input data on the two classifiers to match the same momement in time. i cannot feed "zero" data on a frame i dont have.

EDIT4: trying to describe my problem and what i want to do better:
I have two list of frames, audio and color. They both correspond to the same length of a recording, for example, they both "describe" 5s of recording.
The thing is, i have less samples of audio than those that i have of color (because of the sampling rates). Now, i need to enter these frames, audio and color, on a Multimodal classifier. the thinf is, i need to know which color frame corresponds to the audio frame, so that i can send them to the classifier as a "single frame" to be classified. I can't do that because i dont know which index of the list audio corresponds to the other index on the list color (and vice versa). So what i'm trying to do is expand the smaller list (audio) to the same count as the larger list (color). To do that i need to replicate some of the audio frames. My problem is to fix this, how do i know which frame is the best to be replicated? I have the timestamps but i'm having trouble sorting an algortihm to do this automotically.

Comment: In the table, it looks like you have 4 colour frames and 4 audio frames, so there's no problem -- right?  I can't tell what you want to do.

Comment: yeah, it's really not clear what you want to do here. Your "color" frames are about 32ms apart and the "audio" frames are 51ms apart. You say they were captured at the same moment, but at different instants", which doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: i have about 100 frames * color * video * 200 files ~= 450 items, 50k frames

Comment: They were both recorded like u record on a video camera. but they buffers are different and they were delivered at different timestamps.  its not releveant the time between frames becasue they are not constant

Comment: I think you need to add to the post 2 things: the reasons behind why do you want to sync the times (also what exactly you want to sync; data or operation) .. and specification of your hardware and model used in here

Comment: Perhaps you want to do something like a linear estimation for color (or audio, but audio is more complicated to be assumed linear even in a small scope) and combine estimated colors on audio timestamps with real audio values.

Comment: And perhaps by sync, you meant "merge". If they are going to be merged, they can't be both real. The answer also depends on what kind of processing/analysis you want to do, and how much real every one of them (color and audio) needs to be.

Comment: Since you can't seem to describe the process you want to perform, a good start would be showing a few examples of some input, and what the output should look like.

Comment: i added a edit4 where i think i explain my problem better! any question say so!! thanks

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can align an audio frame to the most closest (in time) color frame.

```
void align(long[] colorTimes, ColorFrame[] colorFrames,
           long[] audioTimes, AudioFrame[] audioFrames)
{
    assert colorTimes.length == colorFrames.length;
    assert audioTimes.length == audioFrames.length;
    assert audioTimes.length <= colorTimes.length;

    // We assume all times and frames are sorted.
    // Otherwise you can sort them here.

    int lastAlignedColorIndex = -1;

    for (int index = 0; index < audioTimes.length; index++) {
        int timeToAlign = audioTimes[index];
        int alignedIndex = lastAlignedColorIndex + 1;

        int colorIndex = lastAlignedColorIndex + 2;
        while (colorIndex < colorTimes.length) {
            if (colorTimes[alignedIndex] > timeToAlign)
                break;

            int timeDiff = Math.abs(colorTimes[colorIndex] - timeToAlign);
            if (timeDiff < Math.abs(colorTimes[alignedIndex] - timeToAlign))
                alignedIndex = colorIndex;

            colorIndex++;
        }

        enterData(colorFrames[alignedIndex], audioFrames[index]);

        lastAlignedColorIndex = alignedIndex;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer xiao. I believe that what you are doing here is sort them by time. They are already sorted and organized by time, what i want is to have the same numbers of audio and color frames, and for that i need to expand the audio frames to the same number of the color frames

Comment: @virgula24 Well my code here is to remove some color frames to make the numbers same.

Comment: @virgula24 so actually you can write it in a way that each color frame is aligned with some audio frame?  I will try to write another version then.